# ORDER BY MySQL - Organização de relatório

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Tenho um chat e gostaria de exibir os contatos de acordo com a data da última mensagem, pensei em muitas formas de fazer isso mas não está funcionando de nenhum jeito. Como eu poderia trazer estes dados corretamente?

**Estrutura das Tabelas**

A tabela *message* guarda todas as mensagens, porém, cada mensagem tem a *session_id*.

A tabela *session* tem as informações da sessão, ou seja, as mensagens são organizadas por sessão, dentro de *session*, possui o ID do contato.

A tabela *contact* possui todas as informações do contato.

**Objetivo**

Minha ideia é dar o *SELECT* na tabela de contatos, mas organizá-los pelo horário da última mensagem.

Por exemplo, imagine um chat com seus contatos ao lado, você está trocando mensagens com algum deles, mas mesmo que vocês estejam trocando mensagem, este contato está sendo exibido abaixo de algum que você conversou ontem.

A ideia é este contato que você está conversando agora, suba ao topo de seus contatos.

**Exemplo**

Abaixo está um exemplo de um dos *SELECTS* que deram errado, ele até retorna por ordem, mas a cada mensagem, os contatos são repetidos.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM      contact AS c
 INNER JOIN message AS m
 INNER JOIN session AS s ON s.contact_id = c.id AND m.session_id = s.id
 ORDER BY m.timestamp;
```

A coluna do horário em que a mensagem foi enviada é *timestamp*

Se alguém puder ajudar, agradeço desde já!

*OBS:* Meu forte não é banco de dados.

Comment: Seria interessante colocar na sua pergunta o que você tentou até agora, um exemplo dos SQLs que tu tentou mas que deram errado.

Comment: Consegue colocar um exemplo dos dados e da saída desejada para podermos testar as soluções?

Comment: E a versão do `MySQL`? Qual é?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A partir da versão **8 do `MySQL`** você pode utilizar a função [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) da seguinte forma:

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE contact (
  id      INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  contact VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO contact(contact)
             VALUES('Maria'),
                   ('José'),
                   ('João');

CREATE TABLE session (
  id         INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  contact_id INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO session(contact_id)
             VALUES(1),
                   (2),
                   (3);

CREATE TABLE message (
  id         INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  session_id INTEGER,
  message    VARCHAR(100),
  timestamp  TIMESTAMP
);

INSERT INTO message(session_id, message, timestamp)
             VALUES(1, 'Oi', NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MINUTE), -- Conversa da Maria
                   (3, 'Como foi?', NOW() - INTERVAL 30 SECOND), -- Conversa do João
                   (1, 'Tudo bem?', NOW() - INTERVAL 15 SECOND); -- Conversa da Maria
```

---

**Query**

```
SELECT x.contact,
       x.message,
       x.timestamp
  FROM (SELECT c.contact,
               m.message,
               m.timestamp,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.id ORDER BY m.timestamp DESC) AS sequencia
          FROM contact c
         INNER JOIN session s ON s.contact_id = c.id
         INNER JOIN message m ON m.session_id = s.id
       ) x
  WHERE x.sequencia = 1
  ORDER BY x.timestamp DESC;
```

---

**Resultando em**

```
| contact | message   | timestamp           |
| ------- | --------- | ------------------- |
| Maria   | Tudo bem? | 2019-04-09 18:58:16 |
| João    | Como foi? | 2019-04-09 18:58:01 |
```

---

Veja funcionando no [**DB Fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/k6MJvMuXmzZrCt56Vq32N4/0)

---

> [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number)
>
> Returns the number of the current row within its partition.

Em tradução livre:

> Retorna o número da linha atual dentro da sua partição.

---

Para versões **anteriores do `MySQL`** (testado a partir da **versão 5.5**):

**Query**

```
SELECT z.contact,
       z.message,
       z.timestamp
FROM (
  SELECT x.contact,
         x.message,
         x.timestamp,
         @sequencia := CASE x.id WHEN @anterior THEN @sequencia + 1 ELSE 1 END AS sequencia,
         @anterior := x.id
    FROM (SELECT c.contact,
                 m.message,
                 m.timestamp,
                 c.id
            FROM contact c
           INNER JOIN session s ON s.contact_id = c.id
           INNER JOIN message m ON m.session_id = s.id
           JOIN (SELECT @anterior := 0, @sequencia := 1) AS y
           ORDER BY c.id,
                    m.timestamp DESC
         ) x
) z
  WHERE z.sequencia = 1
  ORDER BY z.timestamp DESC;
```

---

**Resultando em**

```
| contact | message   | timestamp           |
| ------- | --------- | ------------------- |
| Maria   | Tudo bem? | 2019-04-10 12:19:28 |
| João    | Como foi? | 2019-04-10 12:19:13 |
```

---

Veja funcionando no [`DB Fiddle`](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/k6MJvMuXmzZrCt56Vq32N4/2).

---

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! O único ajuste agora é colocar um WHERE para capturar apenas os contatos do ID de usuário que está logado, você sabe onde colocar essa condição?
Se for possível editar a resposta com a cláusula, agradeço.
OBS: A coluna user_id está na tabela contact.
Me ajudou muito, obrigado amigão!

Comment: @VictorHugo infelizmente foge ao escopo da pergunta e eu ainda teria que responder isso sem ter a estrutura completa e sem saber a versão do `MySQL`, então só posso sugerir que você coloque o `WHERE`  logo abaixo dos `JOINs`.

Answer (score 0):

Veja se esse SQL te ajuda em algo:

```
select distinct 
       c.campo1
      ,c.campo2
      ,c.campo3
      ,c.campo4
  from      message m 
 inner join session s on s.id = m.session_id
 inner join contact c on c.id = s.contact_id
 order by m.timestamp;
```

No caso do SQL acima, só serão retornados os dados dos clientes que possuírem pelo menos uma mensagem enviada.
Como só vai precisar dos dados do contato, acredito que usando `distinct` já resolva o problema de trazer dados duplicados.

Comment: Funciona, porém, os contatos são exibidos repetidamente

Comment: @VictorHugo Você só vai trazer os dados do contato, neste select? Ou vai trazer algo relacionado a mensagem ou sessão também?

Comment: Preciso apenas dos dados do contato

Comment: @VictorHugo Verifique a edição da minha resposta, modifiquei o SQL, tente com o `distinct`

Comment: Está com o mesmo problema, ele repete o contato pra cada mensagem da sessão